# Find the image using the matrix relative to B and B'

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to find the image of a transformation using the standard matrix, however, I don't quite get how you would use two bases to obtain the image. I've searched my whole Linear Algebra textbook for a detailed explanation about solving such a problem. Additionally, I have searched all over the internet for a detailed video or article for solving this problem, with no success. The articles I have managed to find are far too abstract and mathematical to comprehend.

Recently, my professor gave me the problem shown below. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain the process in a detailed manner.

Find the image by using the matrix relative to B and B'.
T: R2 -> R3, T(x,y) = (x + y, x, y), v = (5, 4), 
B = {(1, -1), (0, 1)}
B' = {(1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)}

Sorry about the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $$T(1,-1) = (0,1,-1) = 1 \cdot (1,1,0) + 0 \cdot (0,1,1) + (-1) \cdot (1,0,1).$$ and $$T(0,1) = (1,0,1) = 0 \cdot (1,1,0) + 0 \cdot (0,1,1) + 1 \cdot (1,0,1).$$  So the matrix $A$ of $T$ w.r.t. $B=\{(1,-1),(0,1) \}$ and $B'= \{(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1) \}$ is

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now observe that $(5,4) = 5 \cdot (1,-1) + 9 \cdot (0,1).$ Let $[v]_B$ denote the coordinate of $v=(5,4)$ w.r.t. $B.$ Then $[v]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 9 \end{pmatrix}.$ Let $$C = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Observe that $C$ is a matrix obtained by taking the basis vectors of $B'$ as it's columns.

Then $$T(v) =CA[v]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 9 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 9 \\ 5 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}.$$

In general let $T : \Bbb R^n \longrightarrow \Bbb R^m$ be a linear transformation. Let $B = \{v_1,v_2, \cdots , v_n \}$ be an ordered basis for $\Bbb R^n$ and $B' = \{w_1,w_2, \cdots , w_m \}$ be an ordered basis for $\Bbb R^m.$ Let $[B] = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_n \end{pmatrix}$ and $[B'] = \begin{pmatrix} w_1 & w_2 & \cdots & w_m \end{pmatrix}.$ Let $[T]^{B'}_B$ be the matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t. the bases $B$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and $B'$ of $\Bbb R^m.$ Then $$T(v) = [B'] [T]^{B'}_B [B]^{-1} v,\ \text {for all}\ v \in \Bbb R^n.$$

Note that in case $B$ is the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb R^n$ and $B'$ is the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb R^m$ then $[B] = \Bbb I_n$ and $[B'] = \Bbb I_m.$ But then $$T(v) = Av,\ \text {for all}\ v \in \Bbb R^n$$ where $A = [T]^{B'}_B.$